# How to fix this Click Listener. Its not working properly?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching a single item from firestore. but when I tryg to put `clicklistner` on a Text View its not working. I also tried putting a breakpoint but its never reached.

```
private static final String EXCITING_KEY_TARGET = "eo_target";
private TextView eo_target;
eo_target = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.m_eo_target);
eo.get()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
              testing(documentSnapshot);
           }

           private void testing(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

           }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
               @Override
               public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
               TastyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Load Image", TastyToast.LENGTH_SHORT, TastyToast.ERROR);
               Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
           }
    });


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    eo.addSnapshotListener(new DetailsExcitingOffer(), new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                        eo_target.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(View v) {
                              Uri uri = Uri.parse(EXCITING_KEY_TARGET);
                              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                              if (intent.resolveActivity(getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                                  v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                              }
                          }
                      });
}
```

Comment: Please add the full activity code, the snippet posted here is really confusing. And also indent it please

Comment: are you getting any  FirebaseFirestoreException? because you are returning like "if (e != null) { return; }". so please post FirebaseFirestoreException if you are getting

Comment: Please add the content of your `testing(documentSnapshot);` method and please also responde with @AlexMamo